# Grouping with rowspan and regroup in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, html-table

I have a many to one relationship in Django: Model A and model B.

I need to output a table where the objects are ordered and grouped by names

```
Name            Amount
======================
A name          200
                300
                500
Another name    200
                30
                450
                15
```

The model B has a foreign key to model A, so I need to print all the model B objects and group them by the foreign key.

I know I can accomplish this with the rowspan html attribute and the regroup filter in Django, but I'm not sure how to write the template.

Normally I could just create output all the objects, but I don't want to write the name in every row. So I need to group them.

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for obj in object_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ obj.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this --

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  {% regroup object_list by name as grouped %}
  {% for group in grouped %}
  {% for obj in group.list %}
    <tr>
      {% ifchanged %}<td rowspan="{{ group.list|length }}">{{ obj.name }}</td>{% endifchanged %}
      <td>{{ obj.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For more see [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) and [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged).